# Upload my Yii2 Project to CPanel

Tags: installation, server, cpanel, yii2

I have developed my Yii2 application locally and zipped the file and uploaded to CPanel under File Manager -> Public_html -> data. Now how can I access my application through the web? What is the url for my project? Should I do another installation? Please help me I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projects are accessed trough the web folder. You have to point your Document Root of your domain to that folder.

If you cant make it work, you need to add your directory structure to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for my nonsense, but I haven't done this before. Could you please walk me through this step by step? I have uploaded my app directory folder under Public_html -> data. I know this might not be the right way to do this but I don't no what to do else. What is the next step? I'm lost!

Comment: try to navigate to yourdomain.com/data/application/web or yourdomain.com/data/web - is your application showing?

Comment: No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.

Comment: Okey. I dont have a C-panel, but the document root must be accessible somewhere. Can you find it under domains or something like that?

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?